# How to run installation of my program during installing custom squashfs?

Tags: centos, squashfs

i made a custom squashfs from cestos8 minimal and during os or custom squashfs installation i want to install a my program and make it run as system starts. im a windows software developer this is new to me and im doing it first time. please any guidance or any reference documents to me so i can learn it and improve myself.

Thanx in advance....